# CSS @page header not displaying on each page when printing from TryitEditor on Safari (iOS)

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Running in W3's TryitEditor I currently have CSS:

```
p.hr {
  position: running(header)
}
@media print {
  .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; } 

  @page {
    @top-center {
      content: element(header);
    }
  }
}
```

an HTML element:

```
<p class = 'hr' >Heading placeholder</p>
```

and basic script to print:

```
<script>window.print()</script>
```

I believe I have the right method, but when I run the page, the print preview shows up with my header only on the first page. Is this an issue of my CSS, my methods, my iOS browser, or W3's HTML environment not being equipped to handle @page settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `@page` is not supported in Safari.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page